# AWS Aurora MySQL 5.7 - maximum statement execution time exceeded

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, activex, ado, mysql-5.7

Today I updated our production AWS Aurora MySQL instances (2 instances which form a cluster) from version 5.6 (1.22.2) to 5.7 (2.10.0).  In AWS, I updated the parameter groups (cluster & instance) to a max_execution_time of 1000000000.  I rebooted the instances (multiple times).

Since then, when I run the same SELECT query I've been running for years, which should take 5 minutes to execute, I get "error: Query execution was interrupted, maximum statement execution time exceeded" after about 60 seconds.

I'm running the query from Microsoft Excel using MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver, same as always, using Microsoft's ActiveX 6.1 Library.  The error is in the CloudWatch logs, so don't think it has anything to do with the ADO.  Why won't the set max execution time stick?

Comment: Did you apply changes immediately?

Comment: Yes I did.  I found another StackOverflow question with the exact same issue.  Appears to be a bug in the ODBC driver.  I had to add a line of code in ~50 spreadsheets that sets the timeout for each query